# 2-legged OAuth 2.0 available for google apps?

Tags: google-oauth

I'm a little bit lost... Too many google documentation, I can't find my way.

We have an app on the google apps marketplace. This app use google's APIs to retrieve drive content, calendar information, ... for all users of our client domain. 
Currently we are using 2-legged OAuth 1.0A.

According to the google documentation, OAuth 1.0 is deprecated.
But I cannot find any documentation for using 2-legged OAuth 2.0.
Did I miss something ?
How are we supposed to replace the existing ? 2-legged OAuth 2.0, or anything else ?
Do we have to do any modification on our google marketplace vendor profile ?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the correct process is described here :
https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2

Comment: And there is a video who explains everything : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxX4oNi_Uyc

Answer (score 1):

The 2-legged form of OAuth2 is described in "OAuth2 for server-to-server applications": https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount ; that document explains how the 2-legged OAuth2 flows work, but not how an administrator grants the application the privileges it needs to access the data: This is done via the Admin console settings, where the administrator authorizes the app to impersonate users in the domain. The details are described in https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this is for accessing data as an application. I want to have user's credential. So that the google app's domain user can browse his own google drive (for example).

Comment: @JonathanD. were you able to find how? google docs seem to require wading through entire google index.